# How to transform a second degree differential equation into two first degree linear equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a hard time. I want to generate an equation system with two equations from a second degree equation.

For example, get two first degree equations from :

$$y''=-  \frac k m|y'|y'-g$$

(k, m and g are constants)

And yes, it is a homework, I just can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $v = y'$. Then you get the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
v' &= -\dfrac k m|v|v-g \\
v &= y'
\end{cases}
$$